# how to seach, get values and update data in list of lists python

Tags: python, list

```
list_A = [['STEVEN', 200], ['SUSAN', 100], ['NICRO', 115], ['MIKE', 320], ['JOHN', 50], ['GIGEE', 270]]
```

I want to search for name: search_name = "NICRO"

and program will give me: pocket_money = 115

after that I do need to update the values

addition_money = 9000

update_money = pocket_money + addition_money

then put it back to the list

```
list_A = [['STEVEN', 200], ['SUSAN', 100], ['NICRO', 9115], ['MIKE', 320], ['JOHN', 50], ['GIGEE', 270]]
```

How to do this code.

New question is if I do need to looking for: search_name = "MJ"

but in list_A doesn't have MJ so I do need to add it to the list

```
list_A = [['STEVEN', 200], ['SUSAN', 100], ['NICRO', 115], ['MIKE', 320], ['JOHN', 50], ['GIGEE', 270], ['MJ', 9000]]
```

Comment: can you post the code you have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for money:

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
for i in list_A:
    if i[0] == name:
        print(i[1])
```

Update money:

```
name = "NICRO"
additional_money = 9000
for i in range(len(list_A)):  #can't use for i in list_A because need index for reference
    if list_A[i][0] == name:
        list_A[i][1] += additional_money
        break
    if i == len(list_A)-1:  # only run when all items has been scanned (since there's break)
        list_A.append([name, additional_money])
```

Comment: thank you. all of the questions are solved :)

Comment: one more question please, if the new name is not in list how to append it to the new data in list. I tried to use else and append but the data are added more than one time.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. Do you want to have a new function that adds data, or do you want the data to auto-add new data when you try to update money with a name not in the original data?

Comment: I want to auto-add new data when I try to update money but the name is not in the original data.